# MySQL foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
# Sql to create userdetails table:
    CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
     `user_details_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `user_group_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `email_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `mobile_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `company_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
     `created_by` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_details_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `email_id` (`email_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    # Sql to create qrcode table:
    CREATE TABLE `qrcode` (
     `qrcode_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `user_details_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `qrcode_url` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `allowed_entries` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `used_entries` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `expiry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
     `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`qrcode_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `user_details_id` (`user_details_id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`user_details_id`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_details_id `)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hey guys, I am trying to create the tables above but I keep getting the error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table `esecurity`.`qrcode` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I think it has something to do with the data types but I have double checked to make sure that they are same. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but it would be great if someone can shed some light on the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: umm, `qrcode` doesn't have a foreign key defined on it in this snippet. Can you include the correct snippet please?

Comment: Yep, I just tried the `create table qrcode` here, and works flawlessly. Are you sure this is the SQL is causing the problem? Did you edit it somehow?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry friend, thank you for your response though. I have included the correct snippet.

Comment: @TheImpaler I accidentally pasted the wrong snippet earlier, but I've updated and yes this is the SQL causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the foreign key declaration. There's an unneeded space in the last column definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`user_details_id`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_details_id `)
Error: Can't create table 'qrcode1' (errno: 150)
SQLState:  HY000
ErrorCode: 1005
```

As it is, the foreign key is pointing to a column that doesn't exist.

Should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`user_details_id`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_details_id`)
```

This is exactly why I personally don't use back ticks. I end up making all these silly mistakes, and it takes me a whole day to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Noted, no back ticks. Getting rid of the space fixed everything, can't believe I missed it.